# Offline install of Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 8 without yum or GUI access

Tags: linux, oracle-12c, installation

I am trying to install Oracle 12c on Oracle Linux 8. I have the relevant files (linuxamd64_12102_database_1of2 and linuxamd64_12102_database_2of2), but the installer uses a GUI, which I can't do (I only have console access to the server).
The server is locked down so that I don't have internet / yum repository access.

I have tried following various guides online (e.g. https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/oracle-db-12cr1-installation-on-oracle-linux-8), but they always need yum to install the prerequisites.

I just need a simple, single-database installation - nothing complex. Can someone provide instructions for an offline, console installation of Oracle 12c with all required prerequisites? I can copy files to/from the server over ssh (so I can get files from the internet indirectly)

p.s. I am aware that 12c isn't officially supported on Oracle Linux 8, but those are the requirements I have to work with.

Comment: You can first do your installation on a machine that _is_ connected to the Internet, which will allow you to identify all the prerequisite packages.

Comment: The article you referenced *includes* instructions for a silent (non-GUI) install. The only thing the article doesn't describe is how to setup a local yum repository for missing packages, which the provided answer explains how to do.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is create a local repository using the OL8 install ISO.

[Creating a Local Yum Repository Using an ISO Image](https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/oracle-linux/7/yum/yum-CreatingaLocalYumRepositoryUsinganISOImage.html)

Example `/etc/yum.repos.d/OL75.repo` content:

```
[OL75]
name=Oracle Linux 7.5 x86_64
baseurl=file:///var/OSimage/OL7.5_x86_64
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY
gpgcheck=1 
enabled=1
```

Where `/var/OSimage/OL7.5_x86_64` is the location you mounted the ISO file which you can copy to the host.

Then you can continue based on whatever documentation you found.

Comment: So then the question is, where do I get the installation files from to point the local yum repo at?

Comment: Oracle Linux 8 ISO file downloads are here: https://yum.oracle.com/oracle-linux-isos.html

Comment: @pmdba thanks. Do I need all of them for Oracle 8.6 or just one in particular?

Comment: Probably just the Full ISO.